# Is it possible to run Selenium on Amazon EC2 instance without headless mode?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to use Selenium to load a PDF page on an Amazon EC2 instance *without using headless mode, since I want to load PDFs*. Due to issues described here (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1872), headless Chrome won't load PDFs, but I am having general trouble getting Selenium Python to run on Chrome without adding the "headless" option (which looks something like this):

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True # I want to change this to False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

If headless is set to False, it simply crashes and says something along the lines of

```
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Here is a guide that sets up Selenium on Amazon EC2, but it uses headless as well: https://praneeth-kandula.medium.com/running-chromedriver-and-selenium-in-python-on-an-aws-ec2-instance-2fb4ad633bb5

Any tips/advice?

Comment: To run without headless mode you'll I know you'll need to spawn an X display server to run the GUI crhome, but I don't have experience doing this with selenium. Is it not enough to download the PDF?